# Move Divs on Scroll and then stay there (horizontal sticky bar)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, onscroll

Trying to get my divs to move horizontally on scroll and then stay put.  I almost have it but can't figure out why the positioning is off.  Please have a look at my code and please help me out!  Pay attention to "when" and "whether" divs, ignore first part.

https://codepen.io/pfbarnet/pen/bmOKxP

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    var $w = $(window);
    var $d = $('#oh');
    var $e = $('#what');
    var $f = $('#how');
    var $g = $('#why');
    var $h = $('#when');
    var $i = $('#whether');

    var stickyHeaderTop = $('#when, #whether').offset().top;
    var lastScrollTop = $w.scrollTop();

    var _x = 0;
    var _y = 0;

    $(window).scroll(function(event) {
        var st = $w.scrollTop();

        _x = st;
        _y = st;
        lastScrollTop = st;

        $d.css('right', _x);
        $d.css('bottom', _y);

        $e.css('left', _x);
        $e.css('bottom', _y);

        $f.css('left', _x);
        $g.css('right', _y);

        if ( $(window).scrollTop() > stickyHeaderTop-100 ) {
            $('#whether').css({position: 'absolute', right: '300'});
            $('#when').css({position: 'absolute', left: '500'});
        }
        else {
            $i.css('right', _y);
            $h.css('left', _x);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, it seems good to use `.scrollLeft()`.
https://api.jquery.com/scrollleft/

The following code is using it and setting `_x` to `.scrollLeft()` value. You can confirm to move divs when scroll horizontally.
codepen: https://codepen.io/kuromoka/pen/oaJPxN

```
var $w = $(window);
var $d = $('#oh');
var $e = $('#what');
var $f = $('#how');
var $g = $('#why');
var $h = $('#when');
var $i = $('#whether');

var stickyHeaderTop = $('#when, #whether').offset().top;
var lastScrollLeft = $w.scrollLeft();
var lastScrollTop = $w.scrollTop();

var _x = 0;
var _y = 0;

$(window).scroll(function(event) {
  var sl = $w.scrollLeft();
  var st = $w.scrollTop();

  _x = sl;
  _y = st;
  lastScrollLeft = sl;
  lastScrollTop = st;

  $d.css('right', _x);
  $d.css('bottom', _y);

  $e.css('left', _x);
  $e.css('bottom', _y);

  $f.css('left', _x);
  $g.css('right', _y);

  if( $(window).scrollTop() > stickyHeaderTop-100 ) {
          $('#whether').css({position: 'absolute', right: '200'});
          $('#when').css({position: 'absolute', left: '500'});
  }
  else {
    $i.css('right', _y);
    $h.css('left', _x);
  }
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this.  It works with the div that's coming in from right to left, but how do I apply this functionality for the "when" div that comes in from the left?

Comment: Nevermind!  It works perfectly.  I think I just mistyped something the first time around.  YOU ARE A GENIUS!

Comment: wait, no... still having problems.  Darn it.  Yeah, doesn't work on left div.  Also, I'm having a lot of problems with resizing the window.  Oh well, great start, thanks!